# Can kernel mode programs or drivers read the entire physical memory?

Tags: windows, kernel, kernel-module

Is there any part of physical memory which no program or software can read? Do current systems (PCs where you can Windows 10 etc.) have such protection mechanism?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any part of physical memory which no program or software can read? Do current systems (PCs where you can Windows 10 etc.) have such protection mechanism?

Yes, unfortunately.

- Many firmwares use so-called "System Management Mode" (aka ring -2).
- CPU/SoC manufacturers often have things like [Intel SGX (Software Guard Extensions)](https://software.intel.com/en-us/sgx) or ARM TrustZone, which allow the OS to start a "secure enclave" which has only a communications channel but is impossible for the OS to reach directly in any other way.
- Virtualization is commonly used to run multiple operating systems as virtual machines. Although the restrictions are enforced by the host OS or hypervisor, it's still similar because the VMs themselves still only have access to their own memory areas despite running in "kernel mode">

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing. If a physical memory location had exist which no program or software can read, what would be the purpose of it?